# Is there any way to avoid CORS error with linkpreview.net in axios like trustAsResourceUrl() in Angular?

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, cors, axios

I'm trying to implement [linkpreview.net](http://linkpreview.net) API in my reactJS app using axios but it gives me followin CORS error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://api.linkpreview.net/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=abc.xyz&key='my
>   key here'. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’
>   missing).

here is my axios code

```
axios({
          method:'post',
          url:"http://api.linkpreview.net/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q="+res+"&key="+UserSetting.fetchUrlKey,
          headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
          data: data
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

Please do let me know if I'm doing something wrong!!

Comment: I think that CORS header should be set in backend of your app not in JavaScript

Comment: I'm using linkpreview.net's API. Please do check https://www.linkpreview.net/

Comment: have you tried setting `dataType: 'jsonp'`? also why you are not passing `q` and `key` in data instead of url?

Comment: I tried both data at both place. Also how can I set dataType in axios? in header??

Comment: add new `dataType` attribute after `method`

Comment: still getting same error :/ @Node.JS

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Axios won't provide support for `jsonp` requests and that is mentioned here: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/pull/15

With that he has also provided another recipe for [jsonp](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/COOKBOOK.md#jsonp) using npm package [jsonp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp)

So, you can try it and use something like:

```
var j = require('jsonp');

j('http://api.linkpreview.net/?key=123456&q=https://www.google.com', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use JSONP anymore since api.linkpreview.net now fully supports CORS - both simple and preflight. I'm not familiar with axios but this should work with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.linkpreview.net?key=123456&q=https://www.google.com",
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
    }
});
```